# How can i make Vlan conect with each other in one switch?

Tags: cisco

i have a small network in one floor i make three subnets and i separate each network by using Vlan , the computers work good inside the one vlan but how can i make each vlan conect with each other .

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In order to connect Layer-3 IP-networks seperated by VLANs, you need either a switch with a Layer-3 image which can do inter-VLAN-routing, or you hook up a real router to either dedicated or trunked ports to do the routing for you.

Inter VLAN routing in Cisco is easy set up; just create VLAN devices on top of existing VLANs,  and add IP-addresses, like:

```
! enable IP routing
ip routing
! configure first VLAN interface
interface Vlan 123
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
exit
!configure second VLAN interface
interface vlan 456
ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
exit
! optional: configure a default route
ip route add 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.42.1
end
```

The switch will now route between Vlan123, 192.168.1.0/24 and Vlan456, 192.168.2.0/24. Additionally it will forward packets for other networks to a default router named 192.168.42.1 (clearly the IP-interface for this network is missing, but you get my point).

More information [is available on the Cisco website](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk815/technologies_configuration_example09186a008019e74e.shtml).

Comment: This type of code is not transparent on routers only L3 Cisco switches please update your example title.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You need a router connected into each of the VLANs created by you to interconnect and route the traffic between the VLANs. VLANs act as a completely separate subnets. You would also need non-overlapping IP addressing scheme to achieve that.